# Makes Apache2 aliased directory takes parent's .htaccess file into account

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have an Apache 2.2 VirtualHost where `DocumentRoot` points to `/var/www/mysite.com` directory.
I also have `Alias` to make some pages/scripts located in `/var/www/stuff` easily available (to others VirtualHosts):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /stuff /var/www/stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

The `DocumentRoot` directory contains a `.htaccess` file (`/var/www/mysite.com/.htaccess`) that blocks unauthenticated accesses:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please say the word..."
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite.com/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valide-user
```

When I try to access http://www.mysite.com, I get the HTTP authentication form.
When I try to access http://www.mysite.com/stuff, I don't get the HTTP authentication form: files are freely accessible.

It seems the `/var/www/mysite.com/.htaccess` is skipped when accessing http://www.mysite.com/stuff because files are in `/var/www/stuff` *id.* not under `/var/www/mysite.com/.htaccess`'s parent directory.

The only workaround I've found is to create a `/var/www/stuff/.htaccess` symlink to `/var/www/default/.htaccess` :

```
user@server:~$ ln -s /var/www/default/.htaccess /var/www/stuff/.htaccess
```

Is there any better/cleaner solution?

Answer (score 1):

It would work as you want it to if /var/www/stuff was actually /var/www/mysite.com/stuff and you removed the Alias.  As it is currently, 'stuff' is NOT inside the DocumentRoot, why on Earth would Apache be looking completely elsewhere for the .htaccess file?

Comment: Indeed, _stuff_ directory is not inside `DocumentRoot` on a filesystem point of view, but it is regarding to the URL it is accessed by (http://www.mysite.com/stuff). Regarding to that, the `.htaccess` is not actually _completely elsewhere_.